# I am trying to do a while loop but the output comes out wrong. What is wrong with the code?

Tags: java, eclipse

In advance I am saying that this is for homework. The task is to check that if the input is "m" or "i" then the loop does not happen. However, if the letter is not "m" or "i" then the loop continues asking the user to input a correct answer. However, when I enter a different input to "m" or "i" then it bypasses the loop altogether even though I need it to. Could you please find out the problem?

Here is the code:

```
System.out.print("Would you like to enter your details using the metric (M) or imperial system (I)? ");
    szMetricOrImperial = szKeyboard.nextLine();
    szMetricOrImperial = szMetricOrImperial.toLowerCase();

 if (szMetricOrImperial == "m" && szMetricOrImperial == "i")
    {
        while (szMetricOrImperial == "m" || szMetricOrImperial == "i")
        {
            System.out.print("You entered in an incorrect value.\nPlease enter M or I: ");
            szMetricOrImperial = szKeyboard.nextLine();


            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "m".equals(szMetricOrImperial)

Comment: use equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: It should never enter the while loop as szMetricOrImperial is not "m" and "i" at the same time and the condition used is && in the if statement

Comment: @Darshan Mehta If I use that code and input "n" it still does not go through the while loop and it should do that. Can you clarify please

Comment: @TanvirSourov I tried || but it still is not working

Comment: The main problem is that whenever I put a letter that is not m or i it does not say please try again but goes to the next part of the code

Comment: @red_star_12, here is the code:

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Character");
String szMetricOrImperial = sc.nextLine();

Comment: if (!(szMetricOrImperial.equalsIgnoreCase("m") || szMetricOrImperial.equalsIgnoreCase("i")))
{
       while (!(szMetricOrImperial.equalsIgnoreCase("m") || szMetricOrImperial.equalsIgnoreCase("i")))
            {
                System.out.print("Incorrect");                
                szMetricOrImperial = sc.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.print("Correct");                            
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Correct");                            
        }

Comment: Thanks that works !!